# Are all the heroes summoned by the Horn of Valere ta'veren?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

Artie Hawkwing is said to be the most powerful ta’veren ever, but what about Brigitte and the others Heroes of the Horn? Do you have to be ta’veren to be bound to the Horn?

Comment: I thought the question was pretty clear as it was, but I made some edits to hopefully help it get clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No.

This has been addressed a few times in interviews, which can be found [here](https://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kwt=%27heroes%20of%20the%20horn%27):

- > *Yellowbeard:* I did get to ask a question Terez put me up to.
  >
  > *Brandon Sanderson:* His answer was no, Heroes of the Horn are not always ta'veren at all in their lifetimes when spun out. Sometimes, they even live normal lives and don't do anything extraordinary, like they sometimes spend their lives as farmers, etc.
  >
  > <sub>-- [TGS Signing Report (paraphrased)](https://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=469)</sub>
- > *Matoyak:* Heroes of the Horn, are they corrective mechanisms by themselves, or are they corrective mechanisms by virtue of being ta'veren?
  >
  > *Brandon Sanderson:* Heroes are not always ta'veren. So, yes, they are corrective mechanisms by themselves.
  >
  > <sub>-- [TGS Signing Report (paraphrased)](https://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=471)</sub>

It should be noted that the property of being *ta'veren* is something a person can have in one particular lifetime, and it won't necessarily be preserved when that person is reborn and spun out again by the Wheel. It's possible that some of the Heroes were *ta'veren* in some lifetimes and not in others.

Comment: There's also some interesting discussion about this [in a forum thread](https://dragonmount.com/forums/topic/52304-the-heros-of-the-horn-are-they-all-taveren/?page=2).

Comment: It's also important to note that some people can be ta'veren for only part of their life, and later lose that property, and not just from one life to another. RJ stated that the main three boys are no longer ta'veren after the events of the books even though they are very strongly ta'veren during the books. That means that anyone can either be or not be ta'veren at any given point depending on the needs of The Pattern

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty clear that being ta'veren is not a requirement. Brigitte gets a lot of page-time and I don't believe that it's stated or implied anywhere that she's ta'veren.

Comment: I think we can actually say definitively that Birgitte cannot be ta’veren for the simple reason that she has met both Nicola and Siuan.